# Looking for Sci-Fi cartoon series from early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, steampunk

All I remember is that it was between ~2002-2005.  It was about a boy in a dystopian, almost post-apocalyptic world (lot's of brown\cliff\mountains scenes).  He found a staff with a droid on it (who possibly could talk and gave him powers over electricity(?)) or he stole it from a technomage, and he found it in a cave.

The other thing I remember in another episode is that they were on a hovership in a canyon with a dam which closed water access.  I can't remember if it was a good thing or bad guys plan to steal water from good people.

It felt like either sci-fi or steam punk.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi Stack Exchange David S.  Feel free to edit your post with any additional details if you remember any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably thinking about "[Xyber 9: New Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyber_9:_New_Dawn)" I remember this show too and it took me a lot of digging to find it. The show only aired three times in 1999, 2000, and again in 2007. The first two times it aired they only played ten of its episodes but in 2007 they played the full 22.

> Jack, a precocious, blonde fifteen-year-old who is an orphan, is given the title of the Chosen One. The people of Terrana, a futuristic realm that has is amidst a war, relies upon him as the last hope to save their civilization. If Jack can achieve the Herculean task of destroying Machestro, the evil ruler of the underworld, he will be named king. Jack's greatest weapon against Machestro is the sophisticated computer Xyber 9 that is in the form of a staff. With Xyber 9's power, Jack journeys through Machestro's underworld and to other futuristic lands, fighting intergalactic evil with an ever increasing band of allies. In order to enfeeble the Chosen One, Machestro tries desperately to snare Xyber 9, for without the powerful computer, Jack would be defenseless. And with it, Machestro could spread his disease of evil throughout Terrana and beyond, conquering other worlds and ruling in his tyranny.

**Intro**

Comment: Woah, that's it! Thanks so much for hard work of digging it up!