Cartoon about a teenage boy with a robotic, talking staff
I've been looking for a while now to try find a cartoon I watched around the late 90's or early 2000's.
It was about a teenage boy who had to save the world. He had a talking staff that was robotic; the top was a circle. I think, as they travelled about, they got more upgrades? The bad people were trying to stop them; I can't remember much about that.
I can't remember too much more as it was a long time ago, but I would remember if I saw a picture. I think it was an American cartoon?

Aw man... I think we had this one. Let me look around.

Is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95013/looking-for-sci-fi-cartoon-series-from-early-2000s your story?

I have found it, Xyber 9: New Dawn

Even for self-answers, we require people to provide more details. :) Can you [edit] some in?
